# Debug Environment Variables in Apache VirtualHost

Tags: apache, environment-variables, mod-proxy

I'm using ProxyPass while attempting to set a request header in my vhost w/:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ...
    RequestHeader set X-REMOTE-USER "%{REMOTE_USER}s"
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9292/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9292/
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

However when inspecting the headers that are getting sent to my application running on port 9292 I see:

```
"HTTP_X_REMOTE_USER"=>"(null)"
```

Does this mean that `REMOTE_USER` is not set or am I using `RequestHeader` incorrectly? Is there a way to debug what environment variables I have available to me within the vhost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that, those variables are available for `mod_rewrite` but not to `mod_headers`.

Here you can found a complete answer to a similar problem:

- [REMOTE_USER through Apache reverse proxy](https://serverfault.com/a/231577/360287)

To get a list of all available enviroment variables you can use `printenv` command in the server, or browse this list of [common enviroment variables](https://www.freeipa.org/page/Environment_Variables).

Comment: Why is `REMOTE_USER` available to `mod_rewrite` but not `mod_headers`? Is there documentation that explains this behaviour?